# How to diplay a check-box list in a course registration portal with Yii2

Tags: yii2

I just started using Yii2, so basically I am a beginner. I am working on a course registration portal, and I am stuck. I am trying to create a dependent drop-down from faculty to department then to the course, so far I got the drop-down working but now I want the course field to show as a checkbox list. Right now it shows as a drop-down list.

Here is my code for the form:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\FacultyTbl;
use app\models\DepartmentTbl;
use app\models\CourseTbl;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\RegistrationTbl */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
$faculty= ArrayHelper::map(Facultytbl::find()->all(),'id','faculty');
$department= ArrayHelper::map([], 'department_id', 'department');
?>

<div class="registration-tbl-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>



    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'gender')->dropDownList( 
        ['prompt'=>'Select....', 'Male'=>'Male', 'Female'=>'Female']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'faculty')->dropDownList(
         $faculty,
        [ 'prompt'=>'Select a Faculty',
           'onchange'=>'
           $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('department-tbl/lists?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
            $( "select#registrationtbl-department" ).html( data );
        });'
         ] );         
    ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'department')->dropDownList(
       $department,
        ['prompt'=>'Select a Department',
         'onchange'=>'
         $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('course-tbl/lists?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
         $( "select#registrationtbl-course_code" ).html( data );
     });'
      ] );
    ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'course_code')->dropDownList(

        ['prompt'=>'Select Courses',

        ]
    )
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Add Course') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: add code for the `$.post` route used for the `onchange` event in the `department` drop-down `Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('course-tbl/lists')`.

Comment: i got it showing now the issue is saving it, when i click save it just says course code cannot be blank and i even tried using a drop down widget in place of the checkbox list but it keep saying course code must be a string

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `checkboxList` method of `\yii\widgets\ActiveField`, see here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#checkboxList()-detail

Here is a usage example: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-activeform-input-fields/#Checkbox-List-Input-Field

This will get you started...

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'department')->checkboxList($department); ?>
```

Comment: did you have a look at my code, where i have the last drop-down, thats where i want to have the list of the courses in a checkbox list or a dropdown list, i tried with the checkboxlist,  but it didnt show any list

Comment: I got it working , but it's saving just a single value to the database ..is there a way I can make it save multiple at once please

Comment: Can you update your question with your new requirement and show your model code? I will have a look for you.